# SQL query to Rank Customers by the number of unique merchants they have used

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I am trying to Rank Customers by the number of unique merchants they have used.

Request you to help me out with the SQL code.

You can view the data from the below link:
***https://www.kaggle.com/ntnu-testimon/banksim1#bs140513_032310.csv***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select cust, count(distinct merchant) as uniue_merchants,
       dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct merchant) desc) as seq
from table t
group by cust;
```

Comment: Thank you @Yogesh Sharma, this query works for me. Is it also possible to display the non-aggregated column or a column which isn't included in the group by clause. in the above query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using `dense_rank()` window function in `MySQL 8.0`. Here is the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8LjGBy82uuR3GBrShHdEGY/0)

*without subquery*

```
select
    customer,
    count(distinct merchant) as total_unique_merchants,
    dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct merchant)) as rnk
from myTable
group by
    customer
```

*with Subquery*

```
select
    customer,
    total_unique_merchants,
    dense_rank() over (order by total) as rnk
from
(
    select
        customer,
        count(distinct merchant) as total_unique_merchants
    from myTable
    group by
        customer
) val
```

Comment: Thank you @zealous, this works for me